# How to dynamically style Cluster layer without style function

Tags: openlayers-3

How can I define the style of a cluster layer as an `ol.style.Style` object, and not as a function, in Openlayers 3?

I am using  a library (ol3-google-maps) which only accepts `ol.style.Style` objects for styling. The [official cluster example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/examples/cluster.html) uses a style function to dynamically add the number of features in each cluster to it's icon:

```
style: function(feature, resolution) {
  console.log(feature);
  var size = feature.get('features').length;
  var style = styleCache[size];
  if (!style) {
    style = [
      new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: 10,
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#fff'
          }),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#3399CC'
          })
        }),
        text: new ol.style.Text({
          text: size.toString(),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#fff'
          })
        })
      })
    ];
    styleCache[size] = style;
  }
  return style;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What kind of object do you want? What library are you referring to?

Comment: Hi Alvin,
In the above code, the style attribute is taking a value from the function(feature,resolution).I want to directly make an object of ol.style.Style  instead of using the function.
I am using mapgears library for integrating google maps with ol3 :-  https://github.com/mapgears/ol3-google-maps
At present, the library does not take functions as values of style attribute.

Comment: I don't think clustering without a style function is currently possible in ol3.  I'd be happy to hear more about this, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ol3 style functions are great when the style depends on some property of the feature, such as the number of subfeatures in a cluster. There is no other way to use dynamic properties in the style.

You could use a common style for the cluster layer that does not depend on the cluster size (that does not show the number of features), such as [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/uctr8m76/2/).

However, you could also set a non-dynamic style for each feature, instead of each layer. That style could be calculated based on it's properties, giving you some of the possibilities of a style function.

[This example](http://jsfiddle.net/uctr8m76/1/) is a modification of the official example that does not use a normal style function. Instead, it listens to the `addfeature` and `changefeature` events of the cluster source, and sets a style based on it's properties to the feature itself (see code below).

Not that this is not a general solution or replacement for style functions, although it should work fine for cluster sources. Notably, you lose the possibility to generate styles based on the resolution. Setting a style to a feature might not be desirable if the feature is used by other layers. You also have to consider performance issues.

```
var styleCache = {};
var styleFunctionIsChangingFeature = false
var styleFunction = function (evt) {
    if (styleFunctionIsChangingFeature) {
        return;
    }
    var feature = evt.feature;
    var size = feature.get('features').length;
    var style = styleCache[size];
    if (!style) {
        style = new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
                radius: 10,
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: '#fff'
                }),
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: '#3399CC'
                })
            }),
            text: new ol.style.Text({
                text: size.toString(),
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: '#fff'
                })
            })
        });
        styleCache[size] = style;
    }
    styleFunctionIsChangingFeature = true
    feature.setStyle(style);
    styleFunctionIsChangingFeature = false
};

clusterSource.on('addfeature', styleFunction);
clusterSource.on('changefeature', styleFunction);
```

Comment: Alvin,Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: Alvin, could you please remove one doubt of mine?
Why is the style attribute always defined as an array but not directly ol.style.Style object ?

Comment: It is not always an array. The style option of `ol.Feature` and `ol.layer.Vector` is either a single `ol.style.Style`, an array of such objects or a style function returning such an array. When setting a static style, an array of one style is equivalent to setting the style without the array. Arrays of styles are useful when several styles are used for the same feature(s). I removed the array from the answer.